# Azure Runbook Error, AzureRmStorageAccountKey Cannot Index into null array

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to run this command within an Azure Run book

`(Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -Name $defaultStorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $defaultResourceGroupName).Value[0]`

It runs fine on my local machine and I can see the Storage Account Key. However, when I run the same command in Azure Runbook it throws the following error

```
Cannot index into a null array
```

If I just run `Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -Name $defaultStorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $defaultResourceGroupName` in the Azure Runbook, it runs fine and I can see the Keys. It is just when I am selecting an element from an Array that it fails and throws an error.

The PowerShell version is 5 on my local machine and on Azure Runbook.

Update:

My issue was resolved after updating the Modules from the Gallery in my automation account.

Comment: try doing `get-member -inputobject (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -Name $defaultStorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $defaultResourceGroupName).Value` and post the result

Comment: I have run the command you suggested and it is throwing this error `get-member : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet`

Comment: well, there's no property named `value` try doing `get-member -inputobject (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -Name $defaultStorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $defaultResourceGroupName)` and see all the properties that exist

Comment: the output i get is `Equals Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
tem.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method     type GetType()                
ToString    Method     string ToString()             
Key1        Property   string Key1 {get;set;}        
Key2        Property   string Key2 {get;set;}      `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I test your cmdlets in my runbook, I could get storage key.
[image]

You could use the following commands to login your subscriptions.

```
Write-Verbose "Get connection asset: $ConnectionAssetName" -Verbose
$connectionName = Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"
$AzureCredentialAssetName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $AzureCredentialAssetName        

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$key=(Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -Name <storage account name> -ResourceGroupName <resource group name>).Value[0]
"The storage account key is $key"
```

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual#step-5---add-authentication-to-manage-azure-resources).
Update

You need update Azure Storage account module version in automation account, then you could solve this issue.

Comment: I have run your script and it still throws the same Error. `Cannot index into a null array` I do not think it has to do with the Log in. As the following runs successfully `Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -Name "xxx" -ResourceGroupName "yyy"` and it shows the output as `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.StorageAccountKeys`

Comment: It is strange, the data type is wrong. According to this data type, you should use `(Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -Name $defaultStorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $defaultResourceGroupName).Value`, if you uses `value[0]`, you will get the error `Cannot index into a null array`.

Comment: I test in my lab, my data type on runbook is `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.StorageAccountKey Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.StorageAccountKey`. So I could use `value[0]` or `value[1]`.  Do you ensure you use an ARM storage account and select correct subscription. 



`

Comment: The root cause your key data type is wrong. I suggest you could try to create a new ARM storage account and test get the storage key in runbook.

Comment: I use the same script within my Create HD insight cluster powershell script to create HD Insight cluster daily from my local machine. If there was an issue with the ARM storage why would it work when invoking it from my local machine?

Comment: It is strange. What do your storage accounts used for? I could test in my lab, my runbook could get storage account key correctly.

Comment: @jane I test a HDInsight  storage account, it also works for me. If possible, could you share more detailed script?

Comment: The storage account is used for storing Cluster data as well as some application configuration files i.e. JSON, Jars and Text

Comment: The powershells script to create an HD Insight Cluster is long, Where it was failing was because of `$defaultStorageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -Name $defaultStorageAccountName  ResourceGroupName $defaultResourceGroupName)[0].Value`  Because it was not able to retrieve storage Key. So I ran the command `Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -Name $defaultStorageAccountName` `-ResourceGroupName $defaultResourceGroupName` to see if it works and it does work but when you try to access the value using `.Value[0]` it throws `Cannot index into a null array`

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the `version` of powershell `Cmdlets`. When I run `Get-Module AzureRM.Storage -List | Select-Object Version` on my local machine the version is `2.1.0` However when I run it in a Runbook the version is `1.0.3`

Comment: Sorry, I am not office, I will test it tommower, if possible, you could try to upgrade your ARM.STOAGE module in automatin accout. I will give you test result tommower.

Comment: I resolved this issue by updating `Modules` for my Azure Automation Account